# Is there a simpler way to cycle back to the start of a list?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
int index = currentIndex;
do
{
    if (index == list.Count - 1)
    {
        // At the end, cycle round to the start
        index = -1;
    }

    index++;
}
while (list[index] satisfies some condition);

// Do something with list[index]

currentIndex = index;
```

which clearly works and isn't really that inefficient.

However, this code gets called quite a few times and I was wondering if it could be made more efficient or cleaner in some way.

Comment: I think it would come down to what you are doing inside the loop that would determine how to make the index go back to -1. Can you not loop over the list itself so that you dont have to reset the index?

Comment: @Jawad It's a list of folder/directory names got via system calls. I *could* put it into a linked list, but I'm not sure that'd be any quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case nonempty list you can use [remainder operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-):

```
index = index % list.Count
```

as for efficiency it is needed to be benchmarked.

**UPD**

as [Šimon Kocúrek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5521670/%C5%A0imon-koc%C3%BArek)  said in the comments you can merge increment and reminder into one operation:

```
index = (index + 1) % list.Count
```

Comment: This is the clean solution. (also could be improved to `index = (index + 1) % list.Count`). As for efficiency, this is as simple and efficient as it gets. If this is bottleneck, you should rather find a way to not do this at all.